# Red River Gorge Summer

Tags: rock-climbing, preparation, united-states, sport-climbing

I'm planning a rock climbing trip this summer and I've been considering the Red River Gorge as a possible stop. I've been there before in the late fall and it was absolutely awesome in terms of sport climbing, but what about the summer? Is it buggy/too humid?

Comment: I was there before in late may and it was pretty hot. I hear June/July/Aug is super hot but that shouldn't matter too much if you find shaded areas or are into super steep routes! Have Fun!

Answer (score 2):

Red River Gorge is one of my favorite places I've climbed and I've *only* been in the summer months. Yes it is more humid, but it's not unbearable, though I'm from the Southeast so I'm a bit used to that. I found that I still enjoyed the climbing enough that I don't remember being bothered by the weather conditions. In fact I think the evenings were a bit cool in August.

In short, it's humid and somewhat buggy, but still very much worth it.